# Getting empty brackets in web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to retrieve data from the Yahoo finance website, but I am getting empty brackets.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import re

initianPattern="<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)">(.+?)</span>"

pattern=re.compile(initianPattern)

htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL")  
htmltext=htmlfile.read()

result=re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

print result
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

HERE IN initialpattern variable pattern is not showing which is

```
`<pre>
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)">(.+?)</span>
</pre>
```

PLEAE ANSWER ME WHY I AM GETTING OLD BRACES

Comment: You really shouldn't abuse the answers like this, you can update you original answer. Also you might want to 'escape' certain characters in your pattern which you can do with  \ so for example \<span ...

Comment: @Pang I can't see the question. I just do 'help and improvement' and I just see wrong part.

Comment: @Pang I rollback. Thank you for your comment :)